# Align two divs to be side by side and then center both divs horizontally and vertically

Tags: javascript, css, html

I tried looking around SO, but I can't really figure out anything that works.

As the title says, I need to align two divs to be centered and side by side.

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="dashboard" style="width: 70%;">

    <h3 id="dash" style="color:#99FF00; font-family:monospace;">

        <table style="color:#99FF00; font-family:monospace;" cellpadding="7">
            <tr>
                <td>generation</td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>currently living</td>
                <td><p id="initial_current"></p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>recently newborn</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>recently died</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>recently surviving</td>
                <td>n/a</td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <table style="color:#99FF00; font-family:monospace;" cellpadding="7">
            <tr>
                <td>total living</td>
                <td><p id="initial_total"></p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>total newborns</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>total deaths</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>total survived</td>
                <td>n/a</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>the answer to life</td>
                <td>?</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </h3>
</div>

<div id="board" style="color:#99FF00; font-size:15pt; font-family:monospace;">
</div>
```

Basically, the 'wrapper' is the parent div. I want to center 'dashboard' and 'board'. I hava javascript generating the text within 'board'.

I roughly want it looking like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use position absolute and declare the margins as follows and you are good to go

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/33Fzu/1/)

```
<style>
.container {
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   margin-left: -150px; /* Half of width */
   margin-top: -50px;    /* Half of height */
}

.left {
   float: left;
   width: 150px;
}

.right {
   float: right;
   width: 150px;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Note: Don't forget to clear floats using `clear: both;` else use `overflow: hidden;` on the container div, currently am using `height: 100%;` so no issues here

Comment: Your solution can cause him problem since you are not telling him how to cancel floating effect using clear or css .clearfix that may cause a problem to the rest of the elements in the page

Comment: @Adidi Atleast expect from him to clear floats :) than too I'll specify

Comment: @Adidi btw there's a difference between inline and floats :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien thanks, so it seems to be centered horizontally, but its awfully low--really at the bottom of the page. any way to incrementally adjust it up until i see fit?

Comment: @kpscript It is calculated, so no way its low, still if you want you can play with the margins I've set :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien hm, it is actually low, but do you think its because i have other elements on the page? sorry, i'm still a bit of a beginner. here's a ss: http://i.imgur.com/zdE3AW5.png

Comment: @kpscript It's because you have not changed the height and width in my style, so change them according to your container div

Comment: @Mr.Alien awesome youre right! is there a way to make it so that on opening, the browser view is that its centered? it is 'centered', but you have to scroll down to realize theres more space on the bottom. i actually don't want any scroll. id like it to open up and what you see is all thats there and its centered. is that possible?

Comment: oh and last question, how would i add divs to this horizontal layout? say, if i wanted to add a third and one still have all of them centered?

Comment: @kpscript adjust the widths off inner divs and float left the second div, add third div and adjust the widths again :)

Answer (score 2):

solution without floating: http://jsfiddle.net/GzvJH/

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
 </div>
```

and css:

```
.container{
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   line-height: 500px;
   text-align:center;
   border:1px solid red;
}

.child{

   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   border:1px solid black;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You should make your div's into span's if you want the `inline-block` to work on earlier versions of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .container {
        text-align:center;
    }
    .twocolumns {
        width:50%
        display:inline-block;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">

    <div class="twocolumns">
          <p>Look at me im in column 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="twocolumns">
          <p>Look at me im in column 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope that helps!